# How to find the number of threads in a OpenVZ containers

Tags: thread, openvz

A am running a Spark application, it is possible to specify some parameters like  the number of threads. 
My question : how I can find the number of threads in my container OpenVZ.
Some details :

```
$lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                64
CPU family:            6
Model:                 45
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               2294.304
BogoMIPS:              4588.60

$ nproc 
24

$nproc --all
64
```